# Code completion in a project, that uses yii framework

Tags: yii, aptana

I have a problem with code completion in my project. I use yii framework, and all lib files has been added into include path.

Following screenshoots will how you what i mean:

1. When i press ctrl+space to view Yii env variables i get following result:

http://tablica.rzeszow.pl/images/screen1.jpg

2. In other php ide (jetbrains|eclipse pdt|netbeans) it works good, as on following screen:

http://tablica.rzeszow.pl/images/screen3.jpg

I configured include path correctly (just add Lib in PHP Buildpath).
Any ideas how to configure (or maybe there are pathes) Aptana to "see Yii::app()" code completion?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do not include yiilite.php as the PHPDoc (needed for autocomplete) etc has been stripped in this file.

Comment: I removed the file called "yiilite.php" and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

http://firas-vision.com/aptana-yii-2/

please check this solution worked for me , no new plugin , it is just a code fix for com.aptana.editor.php.jar plugin

I pulled a request to change on Aptana git , hope they will include this fix in the next release